# Upgrade to 14.04.1 to 12.04 by mobile internet

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, data-loss

How much data will be downloaded upon upgrading to 14.04.1 from 12.04? Can I upgrade using a mobile internet connection?

Comment: of course there will be data usage while upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04.1 but i am not sure how much but might be in range of 400-500 megabyte.

Comment: re. "can i upgrade though mobile INTERNET?" it would helpful if you used a fast connection that doesn't drop even though the upgrade process is relatively robust. There should be no data loss but you are always advised to back up your data at all times.

Comment: Also you may want to download the installation iso and use it instead. I think during installation you have the option to upgrade existing Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 1):

- There is a low but relevant risk, that upgrading to another release will damage the data in your home directory or anywhere outside of system folders. Keeping a backup of important data in case of a hardware failure, a software bug, or a user error is a good idea anyway. There's a saying that “data without a backup is unimportant data.”
- You should always have [a bootable Ubuntu live system](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) on a removable storage medium prepared and handy while upgrading in case the upgrading procedure is stuck in an inconsistent state or booting becomes impossible for some other reason. Downloading that is roughly 1 GB.
- The mode of internet connection is irrelevant for the upgrading process, as long as it's stable (which may be a problem with mobile connections depending on the local service). You may need to re-install drivers once you boot the new kernel after the procedure is finished, if it doesn't work out of the box.
- I agree with [bolzao](/questions/552558/upgrade-to-14-04-1-to-12-04-by-mobile-internet/552575#comment757548_552558) that the upgrade procedure should download roughly 400–500 MB. If you have an external installation medium (like I suggested to have anyway), you can use it as a package source, so you don't have to download packages twice. Ubuntu should offer you to register its installation medium as a package source as soon as you put or plug it in.

Comment: I cannot add anyhing useful, except that I *strongly agree* with David: Just download the CD, (or have your brother/father/sister/neighbour do it for you) *confirm the checksum*, burn it and use that.  Upgrading over mobile is a not risk I would be wiling to take!